# How to handle apt installation which produce one more configuration dialog screens using python-apt?

Tags: python, apt

For example when installing lirc package it gives configuration dialog screen. How to automate so as to select default values (or possible to provide spevific values) and proceed?

Right now i have a simple script:

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python
  import apt
  import sys

  pkg_name = "lirc"

  cache = apt.cache.Cache()
  cache.update()

  pkg = cache[pkg_name]
  if pkg.is_installed:
      print "{pkg_name} already installed".format(pkg_name=pkg_name)
  else:
      pkg.mark_install()

      try:
          cache.commit()
      except Exception, arg:
          print >> sys.stderr, "Sorry, package installation failed [{err}]".format(err=str(arg))
```

Configuration Window is as in below link
http://cdn.avsforum.com/d/db/db48d778_vbattach158986.jpeg

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

and then use [`debconf`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/debconf) to provide the values you have chosen.
This [howto](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/perform_an_unattended_installation_of_a_debian_package.html) explains

> If you want to supply an answer to a configuration question but do not want to be prompted for it then this can be arranged by preseeding the DebConf database with the required information. You will need to know:
>
> - the name of the package responsible for asking the question (which might not be the one you asked to install if there are dependencies),
> - the configuration database key against which the answer is recorded, and
> - the type of the answer (string, boolean, select, multiselect or password).

Configuration options can also be provided, in `python-apt` with the [`apt_pkg.Configuration`](https://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/apt_pkg.html#configuration-and-command-line-parsing) class. By example

```
apt_pkg.config.set("Dir", self.tmpdir)
```

You then have to find the name of the options asked by the configuration script and set it via the python script.

Comment: Can you please put an example on how to do this? I'm still extremely confused on how to accept default values from config files in python-apt